# Return type of (long + long)

Tags: java

it seems to be a silly question but I couldn't find the answer or at least I didn't know how to formulate it on Google.

When we add two bytes in Java, the result is an int.

But what about two long, or a long and an int ? Same questions for double and float. I'm a little bit lost between all those conversions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A `long`. This is subject to [§5.6.2 Binary Numeric Promotion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2), item 2:

- If either operand is of type `double`, the other is converted to `double`.
- Otherwise, if either operand is of type `float`, the other is converted to `float`.
- Otherwise, if either operand is of type `long`, the other is converted to `long`.
- Otherwise, both operands are converted to type `int`.

You get an `int` when adding two `byte`s because of the last rule.

Comment: To add onto KennyTM, if you add a double and float together, you get a double (as outlined in first bullet)

Comment: Thank for the accurate answer !